# How to compute the integral $\int \cos x dy$?

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to find
$$\int \cos x dy.$$

I know that if I have to differentiate the same "thing" w.r.t $y$, then chain rule could be used to get 
$$- \sin x\frac{dx}{dy}.$$

But I'm unable to find the integral w.r.t $y$.

I entered it in some online calculators, and the answer I got was 
$$y \cos x + C.$$

Can somebody explain how to get this?

I know this is a very elementary problem, but still I'm struggling with the answer. It would be better if you find the answer using only elementary calculus.

Comment: Before antiderivative, you need to know derivative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you integrate with respect to $y$, you regard $x$ as just a constant.

It's just like how $\int 2\, dy = 2y + C$.  As far as the integral is concerned, $2$ is just a constant.

Similarly, $\cos x$ is just a constant as far as $\int \cos x\, dy$ is concerned, *because* it's an integral with respect to $y$ and not $x$.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to find

$$\int \cos x dy$$

the $dy$ part means you want, as you noted, to integrate with respect to $y$. That means all other variables are to be viewed, inside the integral, as constants. As you know, when integrating you can put multiplicative constants out of the integral:

$$\int af(x)\ dx = a\int f(x)\ dx$$

Therefore

$$\int \cos x dy = \int \cos x \cdot 1\ dy = \cos x\cdot\int 1dy = cos x\cdot y$$